# svm in R, train data set

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, training-data

More a general question, but since I am using R -> tags

My training data set is 15,000 entries big from which around 20 i would like to use for positive data set -> building up the svm. I wanted to use the remaining resampled dataset as my negative dataset, but i was wondering, it might be better to take the same size (around 20) as the negative data set, otherwise it's highly [imbalanced](http://www.ijetae.com/files/Volume2Issue4/IJETAE_0412_07.pdf)?  Is there an easy approach to pool then the classifiers (ensemble based) in R after 1000 rounds of resampling? (or even with the `e1071` package)

Followup question: I would like to calculate a score for each prediction afterwards, is it fine just to take the probabilities times 100??

Thx

Comment: it is a bit general but also ambiguously worded. Entries = features? or samples? 20 samples I'm guessing? I suggest you check the webpage for `caret` package which has very clear explanations of this type of problem: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/index.html

Comment: thanks stephen, features = 5 , 20 samples, scusi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "class weight" approach in which the smaller class gets more weight, thus taking more cost to mis-classify the positive labelled class.